# appending different json dictionaries to a json file via python

Tags: python, json

we are creating a JSON file and inserting different dictionaries into it but the resultant file is giving an error bcoz of the missed place of opening and closing brackets instead of ",".

```
for repoName in tqdm(repoList, total=len(repoList), desc="extracting PR details"):
                consolidated_JSON = {}
                end_cursor, has_next_page = None, True
                flag =0
                repoPR={}
                prDict={}
                while(has_next_page):
                    data = getPrJSON(repoName, end_cursor)
     
                for pr in data["nodes"]:       
                    repoPrDetails ={
                        "PR_number": pr["number"],
                        "title": pr["title"],
                        "id": pr["id"],
                    }
`                    consolidated_JSON[f"PR{pr['number']}"] = repoPrDetails
                     prDict[f"PR{pr['number']}"] = prDetails
                    repoPR[repoName] = consolidated_JSON
            if flag == 1:
                with open("repoPrDetails.json", mode="a") as file:
                    json.dump(`enter code here`repoPR, file, default=str)
```

the file is created like this:

```
{
    "repo1": {
        "PR301": {
            "PR_number": 301,
            "title": "Update configuration.json",
            "id": "MDExOlB1bGxSZXF1ZXN0NDQ1MTM1"
        },
        "PR302": {
            "PR_number": 302,
            "title": "refactor",
            "id": "MDExOlB1bGxSZXF1ZXN0NDQ1MTM2"
        },
        "PR303": {
            "PR_number": 303,
            "title": "Adding us20 az-preprod saas tenants",
            "id": "MDExOlB1bGxSZXF1ZXN0NDQ1MTM3"
        },
        "PR304": {
            "PR_number": 304,
            "title": "logic corrected",
            "id": "MDExOlB1bGxSZXF1ZXN0NDQ1MTM4"
        }
    }
}
{
    "repo2": {
        "PR301": {
            "PR_number": 301,
            "title": "Update configuration.json",
            "id": "MDExOlB1bGxSZXF1ZXN0NDQ1MTM1"
        },
        "PR302": {
            "PR_number": 302,
            "title": "refactor",
            "id": "MDExOlB1bGxSZXF1ZXN0NDQ1MTM2"
        },
        "PR303": {
            "PR_number": 303,
            "title": "Adding us20 az-preprod saas tenants",
            "id": "MDExOlB1bGxSZXF1ZXN0NDQ1MTM3"
        },
        "PR304": {
            "PR_number": 304,
            "title": "logic corrected",
            "id": "MDExOlB1bGxSZXF1ZXN0NDQ1MTM4"
        }
    }
}
{
    "repo3": {
        "PR301": {
            "PR_number": 301,
            "title": "Update configuration.json",
            "id": "MDExOlB1bGxSZXF1ZXN0NDQ1MTM1"
        },
        "PR302": {
            "PR_number": 302,
            "title": "refactor",
            "id": "MDExOlB1bGxSZXF1ZXN0NDQ1MTM2"
        },
        "PR303": {
            "PR_number": 303,
            "title": "Adding us20 az-preprod saas tenants",
            "id": "MDExOlB1bGxSZXF1ZXN0NDQ1MTM3"
        },
        "PR304": {
            "PR_number": 304,
            "title": "logic corrected",
            "id": "MDExOlB1bGxSZXF1ZXN0NDQ1MTM4"
        }
    }
}
```

now the JSON file which we have created gives the error bcoz of  "} {" instead of ","
kindly provide a way to append a JSON file with different dictionaries as we cant hold the data in a single dictionary as the data is huge.

Comment: The indentation of your code looks a bit weird: Could you fix that please?

Answer (score 0):

```
with open("repoPrDetails.json", mode="a") as file:
   json.dump(repoPR, file, default=str)
```

here mode is the "issue".

Suppose the existing data in the file repoPrDetails.json is {"1":{"a":"b"}}. Now when you are running this code again (suppose the data to be written here is {"2":{"a":"b"}}) the code is appending this data after the exsiting data. So new data in file is : -

{"1":{"a":"b"}}{"2":{"a":"b"}}.

You are opening the file each time in the loop.

Now how to fix this -

```
existingData = {}
try:
    f = open("repoPrDetails.json")
    existingData = json.load(f)
except:
    pass

with open("repoPrDetails.json", mode="w") as file:
    repoPR.update(existingData)
    json.dump(repoPR, file, default=str)
```

If you don't want to load all data in dictionary then the only option is to append string in the file while removing the last brackets by seeking to the last position